# Moved mountpoint of MariaDB in docker, now databases gone

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Ok I did a dumb thing, I wanted to rename the local database file that was a mount point for my database, but now when starting the container it shows no databases.

```
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:10.2
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test1234
    volumes:
     - <myhomedir>/mariakn:/var/lib/mysql
```

I changed the database folder in the `<myhomedir>/mariakn` by using a `sudo mv mariakn mariadb`. Then when the new container didn't show any databases, I moved it back, undid the change in docker-compose.

Databases still won't show, but the files are still there in the folder..what can I do to get it back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you ***MUST*** make a copy of the files as backup. Then try `docker-compose up --force-recreate`. Check in mariadb log `docker-compose logs mariadb -f` for any database error, or, your database files already corrupted before?

Comment: Didn't work..well it was all debug stuff in there, so nothing really valuable was lost, just some time to get the databases and testdata running again. Gonna close the question